# Identifying strange amplifier types of amplifiers in a 1979 CB radio

Tags: amplifier, bjt, radio

I'm trying to fix an old Midland 3001 CB radio and I came across a few strange types of amplifiers in the receive stage of the radio. I was wondering if anyone could identify the type of amplifier used.

In the screenshot the direct input from the antenna is coupled through C101 on the left I believe. Then there are some diodes which I assume are used to protect the receive stage. The L101 is a variable transformer that couples the signal to the transistor Q101.

- What kind of amplifier circuit is the Q101 transistor involved in (is it common emitter, common collector, or something else entirely)?
- What is L102 doing at the output (I believe it is a tunable LC
  filter)?

I have also attached the full schematic diagram for the radio.

[image: The amplifier in question]
[image: Midland 3001 schematic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**D101** along with **D105** do protect the receiver input from huge transient events, as OP surmises. They also limit amplitude of the transmitted signal going into the receiver. But **D103,D104** are DC-biased with current from the **RF GAIN** control, to attenuate merely large input signals while receiving.

Common-emitter RF amplifier transistor Q101 has resonators (27 MHz) at both input (L101) and output (L102). C101 (33pf) resonates with L101 @ 27 MHz with fairly low-Q. A small-value neutralizing capacitor (C104) keeps this amplifier from oscillating. It compensates for collector-to-base capacitance inside the transistor.

L102 is a tuned circuit (27 MHz), part of a double-tuned resonator along with L108, top-coupled with a small coupling capacitor (C107, 3pf). This double-tuned resonator has a bandwidth wide enough to pass the whole CB band on to the down-converting mixer.
A noise blanker (NB) module (possibly an optional addition?) also takes its input from this double-tuned resonator.

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing for me is that it is difficult to see how the amplifier is biased at the base and if that the collector does not seem to be connected to Vcc. Also, where exactly is the output being taken from, is it from the emitter, the collector or both?

Comment: DC collector voltage comes in via R105 (470 ohm) to a tap on L102. Amplifier output signal from collector goes to L102, is coupled into the mixer via C107 and resonator L108. Emitter is at DC potential, AC-grounded via C103, C106. DC base bias voltage comes in via R101, through a winding of L101...it includes a DC automatic-gain-control voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly tricky circuit ;)

This is common emiter stage with small positive feedback (C104) - probably for increase the amplification. D110 as a load of L102 acts as limiter - connecting diode as load of LC filter decreases amplitude of intermodulation products. Additionaly, this stage functions as a part of AGC (automatic gain control) - the Q101 base polarisation depends on constant component of voltage on detector output (taken from D107).

**About intermodulation:**

Intermodulation is an effect, which occurs when we have more than one signal on input and the aplitude of one of these signals is large enough that the stage starts to be non-linear. Intermodulation produces wide spectrum of unwanted frequencies: it is combination of harmonics of all input signals. Same of these products can have frequencies near useful band, so will be treated as next stages as useful signal - which is unwanted. It means, that we should provide the first stages as linear as it is possible (technically and economically). Of course, the risk of occurence of nonlinearity grows in the next stages, because the signal is aplified by each stage. It means, we need to limit amplitude of input signal to safe values as early as we can - but limiting always causes nonlinearity, so there will be risk of intermodulation :( The solution is to made limiting after pre-filtering signal: filter significantly decreases the amplitudes of off-band signals, so the risk of intermodulation will decrease.

Comment: What would be causing intermodulation in this circuit and how does the D110 diode reduce it exactly?

Comment: Added description in answer.